# Can age,education level and socioeconomic status be controlled but not as covariates to strengthen an experimental study?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, ancova, methodology, demography

Most ppl include age, education level and socioeconomic status in their demographics just to show their sample of study. But in my case all those 3 factors are predictors of my DV which is prosocial behavior (volunteering). And I hv justifications how different levels of all these 3 factors cn affect my DV. Therefore to strengthen my procedure I want to make all these 3 constant by using young adults and undergraduate students. Should I just include a demographic form and at the same time explain in my proposal for the gap part that I am keeping all these constant to strenghten my procedure.The main articles had demographic forms but their participants were from diff age groups and some were students and working ppl.Therefore I am trying to fix the minor flaws in the main articles.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you control for such variables in an experiment by randomly assigning participants to the treatment and the control group. In your strategy you also control for these characterisitcs (maybe you should still control for socioeconomic status of the parents, as students tend to be quite young and still influenced by their background). The problem with your strategy is the extend to which you can generalize your finding to the general population: Students are very atypical and face very atypical circumstances.